# Script to send values in google sheets to an email

Tags: google-sheets, google-forms

I've found some scripts and try to modify it so that it works for my use case but keep running into errors.  Basically I have a google form, and when user submits, I want the row that they just entered to be sent to my email.  I keep getting an error: "Cannot read property "namedValues" from undefined. (line 14, file "Code")"

Any help is appreciated, thanks!!

```
function sendFormByEmail(e) 
{    
  var email = "dummyemail@dummy.com"; 

  var s = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var headers = s.getRange(1,1,1,s.getLastColumn()).getValues()[0];    
  var message = "";
  var subject = "New Hire: ";

  // The variable e holds all the form values in an array.
  // Loop through the array and append values to the body.

  for(var i in headers) 
    message += headers[i] + ': '+ e.namedValues[headers[i]].toString() + "\n\n";     

  // Insert variables from the spreadsheet into the subject.
  subject += e.namedValues[headers[2]].toString() + " - starts " + e.namedValues[headers[15]].toString();

  // Send the email
  MailApp.sendEmail(email, subject, message); 

}
```

Comment: actually i got this to work using the below code, however how i only modify this to only include headers that have a value?  so if its blank, dont include it in the message. right now its including all headers even ones without a value:

Comment: function sendFormByEmail(e) 
 {

  var email = "dummy@dummy.com“; 
  var s = SpreadsheetApp.openById(“random”)”
  var sheet = s.getSheets()[0];
  var headers = sheet.getRange(1,1,1,sheet.getLastColumn()).getValues()[0]; 
  var datarow = sheet.getRange(sheet.getLastRow(),1,1,sheet.getLastColumn()).getValues()[0];
  var message = "";

  for(var i in headers)
  {
    message += "" + headers[i] + " : " + datarow[i] + "\n\n";
    //Logger.log(message);
  }

  MailApp.sendEmail(email, "Report", message); 
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check if headers[i] is blank, replace:

```
message += "" + headers[i] + " : " + datarow[i] + "\n\n";
```

with:

```
if (datarow[i] != "") {
message += "" + headers[i] + " : " + datarow[i] + "\n\n"; 
}
```

Also if you are allowing users to edit their responses then your data row will be incorrect.  You can use:

```
var datarow = sheet.getRange(e.range.getRow(),1,1,sheet.getLastColumn())‌.getValues()[0];
```

Comment: Hi, i tried this but am still getting the email with some headers that dont have a value.  See my sample data in my email below:

Comment: Detailed Description: : yes

Please choose a category: :

URL: :

Comment: where is the data?  Can you post a shared link to the spreadsheet.

Comment: This is how I modified the code:  var message = "";

  for(var i in headers)
  
  {if (headers[i] != "") {
    message += "" + headers[i] + " : " + datarow[i] + "\n\n";
    //Logger.log(message);
  }}

  MailApp.sendEmail(email, "testsubject", message); 
}

Comment: find the header cells that should be empty and clear them, make sure they are actually empty.

Comment: Hi, below is the link to my test form and file, i cleared the fields but it appears to be sending me an email with the headers with ":" as a value.  Link to spreadsheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1kJ64KnpST4WH0rw6Wx47jVwPvX6BFzkkQ_L2NkmmukE/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Link to test form: https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSefpsdkd7LfOJi6ijGWgzQqpk4s13M3n0_9Pe0_sRhhTpxDPA/viewform?c=0&w=1

Comment: I only see 3 headers in your spreadsheet: timestamp, test question and choose an option. When you say headers what are you referring to?  Please clarify which range you want to check if empty.

Comment: yes this file is just a test one that i am sharing with you, but my actual file has more headers. in the example i sent you, there is a header called "choose an option", which has no value in it for the first row.  However, when user submits the form, my email response still sends me this header and with a blank value.  I would like it so that i dont see the header at all in the email, and only headers that contains a value--thanks for your help!  :)

Comment: so for example in the file above, when i receive the email after user submits, my email should only show the timestamp column with the value, and the "test question" column with the value the user has entered.

Comment: I edited my original answer above to meet your new requirements, it should work now.